# pythonic way of initialization of dict in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a python way of initialization of a dictionary?

```
animals = ["dog","cat","cow"]
for x in animals:
    primers_pos[x]={}
```

Is there something like

```
(primers_pos[x]={} for x in animals)
```

Comment: `animals`? `primers`? Which is it?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a dictionary comprehension (supported in Python 2.7+):

```
>>> animals = ["dog", "cat", "cow"]
>>> {x: {} for x in animals}
{'dog': {}, 'cow': {}, 'cat': {}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use *collections.defaultdict*

```
primer_pos = defaultdict(dict)
```

Then whenever you reference *primer_pos* with a new key, a dictionary will be created automatically

```
primer_pos['cat']['Fluffy'] = 'Nice kitty'
```

Will by chain create *{'Fluffy': 'Nice Kitty'}* as value of key 'cat' in dictionary *primer_pos*

Answer (score -1):

```
hash = {data: True for data in ['a', 'b', 'c']}
print(hash)
```

> Output: {'a': True, 'b': True, 'c': True}

Comment: Please make sure that your solution was not already proposed in an [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40042640/6682517) before posting it.